# Confused with C type casting with characters

Tags: c, casting

I am a Beginner in C programming and I am writing a simple program to encrypt a string to rot13 Ceaser cipher.Now, I know about casting floats and ints in C but I really don't know what's happening below with characters:

I do this `char test = 'A' + 13;`

and I get `N` as output.Fine!! but how? `What's going on underneath? My guess is 'A' is casted to integer both are added and then finally the answer is again casted to a char.
Why is this so?

Comment: `char` is stored internally as an `int`. http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Comment: `'A'` isn't casted (aka implicitly converted), it _is_ an integer (a literal of type `int`).

Comment: `'A'` is recognized as _integer character constant_ of type `int` (not `char`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, types such as `char` are numbers, and `'A'` is a roundabout way to write the `int` value 65 (provided your character set is ASCII, which is the case on all modern platforms). So, the expression `'A' + 13` is equivalent to `65 + 13`, and its result gets cast to `char`, the type on the left-hand-side of the assignment operator.

In other words, it's not that `'A'` that is cast to `int`, it's the `int` sum of 65 and 13 that gets cast to `char`.

Comment: Just to add to this, try doing 
printf("%d %c", test, test);

Answer (score 1):

C treats characters as small integers. For example in ASCII, character 'a' has the value 97 and character 'A' has the value 65.

When a character appears in the source code, C simply uses its integer value.

```
char ch = 65; // ch is 'A' now
ch = ch + 2   // ch is 'C' now
```

or

```
char ch = 'A'; // ch has value 65 now
ch = ch + 2    // ch is 'C' now
```

[image: ASCII TABLE]

Comment: so when I compare a character(char ch = 'A') with a number 
this works --> if ch > 32 but not this ch > '32' ? why?

Comment: A character constant is usually one character in single quotes. There are some exceptions like '\n', '\r' and '\t' because they can't be written in that way. In your comparison 'A' is a character constant that has value 65, but '32' is not a character constant. '3' is a character constant that has value 51 and '2' is a character constant that has value 50. However, '32' is not a character constant because it is not one character.

Answer (score 0):

> test = 65(ASCII corresponding to `A`) + 13 = 78 = N (casted to character)

characters are interpreted as `integers` within `C`..so this happens

Answer (score -1):

Each letter has its numerical representation. The ASCII character set (excluding the extended characters defined by IBM) is divided into four groups of 32 characters. The first 32 characters, ASCII codes 0 through 1Fh (31), form a special set of non-printing characters called the control characters. We call them control characters because they perform various printer/display control operations rather than displaying symbols. Examples includecarriage return, which positions the cursor to the left side of the current line of characters, line feed (which moves the cursor down one line on the output device), and back space (which moves the cursor back one position to the left). Unfortunately, different control characters perform different operations on different output devices. There is very little standardization among output devices. To find out exactly how a control character affects a particular device, you will need to consult its manual.
The second group of 32 ASCII character codes comprise various punctuation symbols, special characters, and the numeric digits. The most notable characters in this group include the space character (ASCII code 20h) and the numeric digits (ASCII codes 30h..39h). Note that the numeric digits differ from their numeric values only in the H.O. nibble. By subtracting 30h from the ASCII code for any particular digit you can obtain the numeric equivalent of that digit.
The third group of 32 ASCII characters is reserved for the upper case alphabetic characters. The ASCII codes for the characters "A".."Z" lie in the range 41h..5Ah (65..90). Since there are only 26 different alphabetic characters, the remaining six codes hold various special symbols.
The fourth, and final, group of 32 ASCII character codes are reserved for the lower case alphabetic symbols, five additional special symbols, and another control character (delete). Note that the lower case character symbols use the ASCII codes 61h..7Ah. If you convert the codes for the upper and lower case characters to binary, you will notice that the upper case symbols differ from their lower case equivalents in exactly one bit position.
You mus not confuse between ' and " the letter betwen ' as 'a' means 1 character its representation in computer memory is 97 and by adding 1‏  ‏
we get 98 which is b
consider the following example
    #include
    int main()
    {
    char ch = 'a';
    //numeric reperesentation of a
    printf("%c = %d\n",ch,ch); 
    ch = ch   15;
    //numeric repersentation of c   15
    printf("%c %d\n",ch,ch); 
    return 0;
    }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for contributing an answer. As a new responder, please note two things. One is that answers need to be to-the-point, wherever possible. Your answer provides a lot of detail about the ASCII character set, but the question was primarily about the C types. Only the last paragraph of your response is really relevant to the question.

Comment: The second thing is that answers are formatted using "markdown", a low-overhead markup language designed so that source documents resemble nicely-formatted text. Since you didn't separate the paragraphs with empty lines, your whole answer ended up as a single block of text, making it hard to follow. The code in your answer must be indented with four spaces, which is easy to do by selecting it and clicking on the "Code sample" toolbar button, the one with the brace parens as its icon.